# Applying intermediate value theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Let $g:[0,1] \mapsto \mathbb{R} $ continuous with $g(0) = g(1)$

Prove that there exists a $c \in [0, \frac{1}{2}]$ with $g(c) = g(c + \frac{1}{2})$

Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $f:[0,1/2]\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=g(x)-g(x+1/2)$. Then, $f(0)=g(0)-g(1/2)$ and $f(1/2)=g(1/2)-g(1)=g(1/2)-g(0)=-f(0)$. Now apply the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: So there must exist f(c) = 0. I started also similarly but got confused defining the domain. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: write $h(x)=g(x)-g(x+1/2)$ defined on $[0,1/2]$$, h(0)$ and $h(1/2)$ have opposite signs.

Comment: $h(1)$ is not defined.

Comment: I suppose the domain is $[0,1/2]$